# Cypress failing randomly during CI testing but passing locally

Tags: vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing

Hey I've created a test that is passing locally wihtout a problem but failing 50% of the time during CI tests.

```
it("Check if scroll is working on list", { retries: 3 }, () => {
  cy.server()
  cy.intercept('GET','**/api/**', {
    statusCode: 200
  }).as('loadMoreAbstracts')
  cy.get('[data-cy=VirtualScroll]', { timeout: 15000 }).scrollTo("bottom").then(() => {
    cy.wait('@loadMoreAbstracts', { timeout: 15000 })
    cy.get('[data-cy=VirtualScroll]').invoke('scrollTop').should('be.gt', 0)
  })
  cy.get('[data-cy=VirtualScroll]', { timeout: 15000 }).scrollTo("bottom")
})
```

Could anybody tell me what can be wrong with this test and why its working locally but failing most of the time on CI? Other tests that require listening to request are 100% passing on CI, only this one has problem somehow but I cant figure it out. Locally it never fails.

Error I am getting:

```
  Check if scroll is working on list:
 CypressError: Timed out retrying: `cy.wait()` timed out waiting `15000ms` for the 1st request to the route: `loadMoreAbstracts`. No request ever occurred.
```

Comment: Since it is a api reliant I prefer such commands to have 60 sec timeout at least, since you do not have control over it. 60 sec is 90% of the time good and in case it isn`t - for example external Api, I sometimes go 120 sec timeout

Comment: @RosenMihaylov do you think that it is possible that the API might be firing bevofre it gets to the cy.wait command? Im not sure how cypress works internally but when you set intercept is it listening for the call immediately or is there a time when the api might be called but before it can be checked for the call?

Comment: I haven`t had such tasks that require `cy,wait(promise)` and `cy.intercept` so not quite sure except I had read they made a lot of changes on it. It is just given that we do not have control over how busy the api is and when a async request gives respose. Thats why I give it a bigger leeway.

Comment: @RosenMihaylov ok I changed to intercept(was using cy.route previously), it works fine locally but apparaently gives same error when deployed. Im so so bad at loss here.

Comment: I can not help more if extending the wait time to 60 000 doesnt work sorry to hear that.